# Google map with default Longitude and Latitude

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

i am using google map with markers
but when it opens it loads with default value and then add my markers
how can i add default center.How can i render this with a latitude and langtitude.

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function () {
```

i am used this but it does not work

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'center', new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0));



<script type="text/javascript">
               $("div[data-role*='page']").live('pagebeforeshow', function (event, ui) {
                   $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function () {
                       var coords = [];

                       $.getJSON('http://teknonova.com/map/Home/getir1', function (data) {

                           var ilkg = 'ilkg';
                           var song = 'song';
                           $.each(data.markers, function (i, marker) {
                               if (marker.PlaceName !== '') {
                                   if (marker.PlaceExtra3 === "1") {
.....
```

Comment: Which library are you using? The one you use resembles this one http://gmap3.net/en/pages/19-demo/ . Maybe you should consider using another library with better documentation.

Comment: i am using this http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false  and you can see my demo here : http://teknonova.com/map/Home/index1

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use this plugin https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_sample_code . That's what I meant by library, not the api. 
You should use some other plugin, with more documentation. Personally I don't use plugins for interaction with the map. Most of them, don't offer much, and lack for good documentation. Myabe [gmap3](http://gmap3.net/)  differs, I don't know.

From what I see from the documentation the following must suffice

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function () {

  $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': '42.345573,-71.098326' });
```

I have a feeling that this will work too

```
 $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': '42.345573,-71.098326' }).bind('init', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code snippet, what the options for the markers are. I suppose you set bounds=true, like this:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { ..., 'bounds': true, ... } )
```

Let's try to remove *'bounds': true*